# Checking for null values in a user object

Tags: php, laravel

is it possible to check for null values in an object in Laravel? I want to check if a user has completed their profile when they hit an api endpoint so that I can let them know they need to complete their profile if there is a field with null values.

This is how the user object will look like

```
    id: 8,
    name: "Jim Jam",
    username: "jimjam@test.com",
    email_verified_at: null,
    dob: null,
    sex: null,
    nationality: null,
    address: null,
    state: null,
    country: null,
    phone: null,
    created_at: "2019-08-03 21:10:20",
    updated_at: "2019-08-03 21:10:20",
}
```

Tried this `is_null($user->sex || $user->phone)` but it returned false.

What are the possible ways to check if a field is null?

Comment: `isset()` `isEmpty()` `is_null()` can all be used

Comment: `if(empty($user->sex) ||  (empty($user->phone) )`

Comment: The most elegant way in my opinion, is Laravel's function `blank()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check a few variables you should check each variable separately. For exampe:

```
is_null($user->sex) || is_null($user->phone)
```

Comment: Well my use case would require I check more than just 2 and would also require I check the user's relationship models also

Answer (score 2):

`is_null($user->sex || $user->phone)` will always return `false`. You are using a boolean OR expression which will always return a boolean, and a boolean is not `null`.

If you want to check twho values, use `is_null` twice:

```
is_null($user->sex) || is_null($user->phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `isset()`. Convert the JSON String via `json_decode($string, true)`. Loop through the array keys and check they're set (not null). Make a new array of those that are not.

```
# Converted via json_decode
$json = array(
    'id'   => 8,
    'name' => 'Jim Jam',
    'age'  => null,
    'a'    => null,
    'b'    => null
);

# Store the unfilled profile properties
$notFilled = [];

# Loop and check that it is set (not null)
foreach(array_keys( $json) as $key)
    if(!isset($json[$key]))
        $notFilled[] = $key;

# Here you'll have a list of all the properties that are not set
var_dump($notFilled);
```

Another way to achieve this is to only return the key, values that are not set with `array_filter()`

```
# Converted via json_decode
$json = array(
    'id'   => 8,
    'name' => 'Jim Jam',
    'age'  => null,
    'a'    => null,
    'b'    => null
);

# Return only if they're not set
$notFilled = array_filter($json, function($val) {
    return !isset($val);
});

# Get the keys (property names)
var_dump(array_keys($notFilled));
```

Or In one easy line:

```
$notFilled = array_keys(array_filter($json, function($val) { 
    return !isset($val);
}));
```

> Output for both:
>       age, a, b

Comment: This is worth looking at some more. In the meantime, I just want some simple way of handling this check using laravel job

Comment: If you want a Laravel approach, add a method to the `User` model like `getFillable` which uses the `$this->fillable` array. Loop through each for the object properties and return ones that are not filled (null) - [See demo](https://3v4l.org/rJlot).

Comment: [See more specific Laravel demo based on above](https://3v4l.org/uFftl) if you want to see how to use it.